# Why are my products description updated in each stores?

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento 1.4.0.1, when I select a product in a store scope (let's say FR store) and update the short description, that short description is being updated in all others store but not in global scope.

I took a look at the DELETE/INSERT statement and here is what I got:

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` WHERE (entity_id='61060' AND entity_type_id='4' AND attribute_id IN('72') AND store_id ='1')
```

The DELETE statement looks correct, it deletes an attribute only from the store id 1

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_text` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES ('4','62','2','61060','FR'), ('4','62','1','61060','FR'), ('4','62','4','61060','FR'), ('4','62','3','61060','FR') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=VALUES(`value`)
```

However, the attribute 62 (short_description) gets updated on each store, however, I'm currently updating it on the FR (store id 1) scope in the back office.

With another database I've (an oldest one) I can't reproduce this behavior, since the code remains the same, I suspect a database config, but I can't find it.

Do you guys have any ideas? I'm a bit stuck and going crazy here.

---

Here are some screenshot from the backoffice:

[image: Short description]
[image: Scopes]

As you can see I choosed the FR store, updated the short description, and get the INSERT statement above, the stores DE & Test are updated as well.

Comment: The scope is website, not global?

Comment: What do you mean? I updated the short description choosing the Store FR scope, but all others store are updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot shows, that currently `[WEBSITE]` scope is assigned to your `short_description` attribute, where you expect it to be `[STORE VIEW]`.

That's why it's updated for all stores in `website` scope.

Check/change the attribute settings in:

```
Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> short_description -> Scope
```